# Android Rendering Live H.264 over RTSP

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm trying to decode (and render) **live** H.264 over RTSP in an Android app.
Assuming, there are no network latency issues, the latency should not exceed several seconds.

The first try was to use the MediaPlayer which was fine but the internal buffering of the infrastructure causes delays of 10-15 seconds.

Right now the main dilemma is between using the new [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) APIs or with FFMPeg.

I know there are many tutorials/samples out there talking about FFMPeg but I didn't see any comparison.
I think I understand most of the pros/cons for each but before spending ages on making one of them working I would like to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen too much info on mediacodec api, I do know that ffmpeg gives you considerably better quality and latency than the built in rtsp functionality in android

Comment: Thanks. We're currently trying to avoid the pain in integrating with FFMPeg.

Comment: what pain, its not that hard really, ok android not as easy as IOS but still couple days to a weeks work at most. Results that we achieved are way better than native. and we decode g711 along with native android audio

Comment: Thanks for the cheer-up. We started the process. Hopefully, it will be fast enough to meet the deadlines.

Comment: if you get stuck we can probably help, I've built a couple android clients, we have a commercial framework for iOS but for android we just handle each client differently, our best success seems to be using sdl , we used the dolphin open source project as an aid to help us writing a player

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there anyway we can get in touch?